# TFS to TFS replication with complete data?

Tags: tfs

I have seen that, there are resources available to migrate complete content from TFS to VSTS. However, i have not seen any good thread talks about the possibilities of getting it done between one TFS instance (2017) to another of same instance (again TFS 2017) hosted in different server?

Comment: Your question is too broad.

Comment: Could you explain more clear about the complete data? Do you just want to move the source code or all artifacts which include builds, work items, release ? Need to keep the history info of source control or not?

Comment: I want to move all artifacts including Workitems, source code, build etc. Also, history should be kept in a sync. 

is it possible somehow?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should confirm one thing, do you need to use the original hardware and TFS deployment or not.

You could perform a **move** when you plan to discontinue use of the original hardware and TFS deployment. You could also perform a **clone** when you intend to continue using the original TFS instance.

*Please take a look at [Move or Clone Team Foundation Server from one hardware to another](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/move-clone-hardware?view=tfs-2015)*

***Note:*** If you want to do a colne option, you need to [reconfigure server IDs and remap databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/move-clone-hardware?view=tfs-2015#clone-option-reconfigure-server-ids-and-remap-databases).